# Open fullscreen modals using primeng dynamic dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using the PrimeNg modal extension for displaying modal popups in one of the Angular webapp I am working on. I am passing a component to the modal service as shown in the following code:

```
const ref = this.dialogService.open(LogsComponent, {
            data: {
                releaseID:row.release_id
            },
            header:'Migration Logs',
            width:'100%', 
            height:'100%'
        });
```

I am getting the `ID` that I passed and is able to display a table in the modal. Now the problem is even if I give `100%` width and height, the modal is not appearing as full screen. I would like to have the modal maximized as it is for the PrimeNg Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For primeng ~13 using the p-dialog tag, you can do the following:

```html
<p-dialog #dialog (onShow)="dialog.maximize()">dialog text</p-dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I asked it three years ago, and at that time, I somehow managed to open the fullscreen model. Thanks for looking into this and updating with the relevant answer.

Answer (score 2):

put these to styles.css. It accepts all dialogs if you want to only this one then give custom class and change ui-dialog with with custom class name

```
.ui-dialog {
    max-height: 100%;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

with custom class

```
const ref = this.dialogService.open(LogsComponent, {
            data: {
                releaseID:row.release_id
            },
            header:'Migration Logs',
            width:'100%', 
            height:'100%',
            styleClass:"customModal"
        });
```

and in styles.css

```
.customModal {
    max-height: 100%;
}
.customModal .ui-dialog-content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me!

.HTML

```
(click)="openDialog(dialogCaidas)"

<p-dialog
  [(visible)]="displayCaidas" 
    #dialogCaidas
>
```

.TS

```
import { Dialog } from 'primeng/dialog';

  openDialog(dialog: Dialog) {
    this.displayCaidas = true;
    dialog.maximized = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use maximizable='true' for your dialog

Comment: This doesn't work on a dynamic dialog, only on the PrimeNg "normal" dialog. So this answer doesn't apply to the original question posted, which is for a dynamic dialog.

Comment: in primeNG version 14.1.1, you can use the "maximizable"-Property in dynamicDialogs!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you initialize your dialog dialog like this, using maximizable option provided:

```
 this.dialogRef = this._dialogService.open(ChildComponent, {
        data: {
            item: this.childData,
        },
        header: 'Dialog Header',
        width: '70%',
        contentStyle: { overflow: 'auto' },
        baseZIndex: 100,
        autoZIndex: true,
        maximizable: true
    });
```

Then what you could do after opening a dialog is to set maximized = true for your dialog instances within DialogService

```
        this._dialogService.dialogComponentRefMap.forEach( x => {
            x.instance.maximized = true;
        });
        this._cdr.detectChanges();
```